# Is this Python3? MultiFile Add-On Tutorial

Tags: python, add-on

I'm using Blender 2.79 with Python 3.6 on Linux. I'm trying to learn to set up a multi-module add-on and this is my reference:
[Multi-file Add-on Tutorial](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/creating-multifile-add-on-for-blender/)

Unfortunately I am finding in cases the ".append()" or ".values()" code is failing. I am thinking perhaps this is because I am using Python 3.6 and perhaps the tutorial uses Python 2 (I'm completely new to Python as of a few days ago). Is there a Python version mismatch causing the errors?

If so, is there a recommended multi-file/multi-module add-on tutorial around using Python 3.6?

Comment: It's python 3.  If you have issues with code re `.append()` and `.values()` post the code.  For multiple examples of multi file addons  look in the addons folder. [python package docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: It was actually the above URL on Multi-file Add-on Tutorial which had those errors. In one declaration there seems to be a typo where dual curly brackets are used in one case, then square brackets in the other. However, I tried both ways. What I get is that ".values()" are not valid for modulesFullNames in that example. I forget which .append() was complained about.